# How can I tell if a wordpress site is running on multisite?

Tags: multisite

I'm moving a bunch of websites from independent installs to a single multisite install.

This seems to be going smoothly, but I noticed that the upload directories have changed from `<upload directory>` to `<upload directory>/sites/<site id>`.

While the change in the link appearance is unlikely to cause me any real trouble (even though I tend to care about link stability), I don't like that an implementation detail as the multisite install is "leaks" through this public facing path.

Can you think of any other "giveaway" that a website is using multisite?

Comment: If this post is about _"security through obscurity"_ (keeping system information in the shades), then I can simply tell you to stop worrying. Each version of WP is _very_ easy to determine and you can't hold someone back from examining if you are running version X with plugin Y and a single or multisite install. Also it's really not worth your time worrying about that.

Comment: Hi Kaiser, I see your point. First of all I'm not really worried, I mainly asked for curiosity. Secondly, it's mostly about stability of links - i.e. if I moved away from Wordpress I would try hard to keep all the links intact in the new system, so it's ironic that moving from one WP install to another something changes. Having said that I understand why this happens and, again, I'm not too worried (although hotlinks to WP hosted pictures are far from being rare).